# Allow rotating components but not the background in Android App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm developing an Android app, and have in the back of my app an image resolution of 500 x 1030, initially vertically. I need my mobile device when you move to another angle, the background remains intact, not rote, but yes, the other controls rotate itself is inside (GridLayout, ImageView ...).

Any ideas?

regards

Comment: The only viable approach I see is that you rotate background image when in landscape view so that it remains in same position as it was in portrait view.

Comment: Thanks kape123, How can I do that? any documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always set the rotation to the view

```
    View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.background_carrying_view);
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //set different image for landscape or set rotation.
        view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.background_land);
        view.setRotation(90);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.background_port);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, is good, but I have a problem when I think the background image that is not a view, I declare as follows in xml:
android: background = "@ drawable / back2", How I can make this a view?